# How to highlight the selected item from basic dropdownlist in ember?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ember.js, css-selectors

I'm using a basic dropdown in Ember and in the list, once we select item in the content list, I want to highlight the selected item. I'd like to know if I can use a simple [aria-current] & [aria-selected] in CSS to make it happen.

hbs file:

```
{{#each pagelist as |page|}} 
   <li class=" dropdown-class" {{action "getAllPages" page dd.actions}}>
        <p {{page.name}}</p>
    </li>
{{/each}}
```

Comment: what is storing the state for your "selected item"? can you add more code?

Comment: I'm not saving any state for the selected item. Should I add it? Had I used "Ember power select" dropdown, it would have added it automatically. But not sure how to do it with basic CSS. 

I tried :active and ::selected but they're not working.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Yes, sure. So, I have a ***Basic Dropdown*** of Ember and the content of the Dropdown has a list. Once I select the item on the list, that item's background color should be changed and should add a tick(Float:right) mark on the right side. I've seen in my code base where we used ***[aria-selected]*** and add CSS attributes to that property. 

***Is there anyway to highlight/apply few CSS properties to the selected item of the list?*** like how we use hover, focus?

Comment: I think this might help you: https://github.com/MelSumner/ember-component-patterns/blob/master/form-components/select-element.md

the gist is that you will need local state for selected item, otherwise _you do not have a selected item_.  a `<select>` element has its own state, which you can use with CSS to do things with (maybe? select inputs are weird tho).

Answer (score 0):

I think the *quickest* way to get you highlighted "Something selected", would be to,

(using ember-source 3.25+)
and: https://github.com/NullVoxPopuli/ember-functions-as-helper-polyfill/ (landing in ember-source 4.5~ish, polyfilled for 3.25+)

```js
// app/components/my-component.js
import Component from '@glimmer/component';
import { tracked } from '@glimmer/tracking';

export default class MyComponent extends Component {
  @tracked selectedIndex;

  select = (index) => this.selectedIndex = index;
  isSelected = (index) => this.selectedIndex === index;
}
```

```
{{!-- app/component/my-component.hbs --}}
{{!-- where does pagelist come from? - let's assume it's passed in --}}

<ul>
  {{#each @pagelist as |page index|}} 
    <li 
      class="dropdown-class {{if (this.isSelected index) 'highlighted'}}" 
      {{on "click" (fn this.select index)}}
    >
      <p>{{page.name}}</p>
    </li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

Note though, that it's an accessibility violation to make `<li>` clickable (and ember-template-lint would give you an error), so you'll probably want a button in the li instead:

```
<li class="dropdown-class {{if (this.isSelected index) 'highlighted'}}">
  <button type="button" {{on "click" (fn this.select index)}}>
    {{page.name}}
  <button>
</li>
```